# Summing input fields with jquery with values using commas

Tags: jquery, input

I'm using this script to sum input fields based on class and return the result to a specified id.

This works perfectly although there are two functionalists I'm struggling with:

`.replace(',',''));` can only cope with one commas, ie 1,000 but not with multiple 1,000,000

I would like the returned result to put back commas every third number, `.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");` does nothing?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        var column2 = $('.left')
        jQuery.each(column2, function (number) {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', ''));
        });
        $('#total').val(sum).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    });
});
```

I have goggled and tried to find an answer but can't find anything that works.

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sumup').on('click',function(){ 
    var sum = 0;
    var column2 = $('.sum')
    jQuery.each(column2,function(number){
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\,/g,'') || 0);
      });
    $('#total').text(sum.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
  });
});​
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/tCXbW/17/)

Comment: If nothing is entered into the input field I want the formula to assume the value is 0 but I do not want a zero to be displayed in the input form. how do I do that? Is there a default value setting?

Comment: Thank you. One more thing sorry! If the user enters a number without separators into the input field although the sum works perfectly the text displayed is not visually good. Can the script add commas every 3 spaces to the value of the input field?

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/tCXbW/19/ what you want? Click on add, input values will be formatted too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tCXbW/23/

this is the problem i'm having. Anything over 9,999 doesnt work

Comment: this is great! thank you, unfortunately I can now not input decimals. i tried adding a toFixed(2) but the commas stopped working

Comment: What you want is tough to achieve with `keyup` as `keyup` is fired after every key press, it will create several problems in case of float values which I cant explain here in thus comment. It can be easily achieved without keyup.

Comment: It can be achieved with `change` which fires when you click somewhere else or a button. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/tCXbW/32/

Answer (score 1):

Use `g`(global) modifier for all replace

```
sum += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g,''));
```

for example

```
var x = '1,000,000';

x.replace(/,/g,''); // output: 1000000
```

and to put comma in every third digit try this within replace

```
/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ','
```

ie

```
$('#total').val(sum.toString.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/, "$1,");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this to remove the commas initially:

```
sum += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ''));
```

Then once you have your sum:

```
$('#total').val(sum.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ','));
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked Joy's solution but have added a few changes to dispense with the need for a SUM button, rather it will recalculate as the user leaves the component fields of the form, which is more interactive and convenient for the end-user:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sumup1,#sumup2,#sumup3,#sumup4,#sumup5,#sumup6').on('change',function(){ 
    var sum = 0;
    var column2 = $('.sum')
    jQuery.each(column2,function(number){
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\,/g,'') || 0);
      });
    $('#total').text(sum.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
  });   
});
```

With the HTML being:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="sumup1" class="sum" value="1,000,000"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="sumup2" class="sum" value="1,000,000"></td>
...
</table>

<div id="total">6,000,000</div>
```